# Constructor Dog in class Dog cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, oop, object, inheritance

Not sure what the issue is here but I am trying to get this program to compile and I can't. I need this to creates and makes the dog, labrador, and yorkie to all speak. The hint I am given is that something is missing in the constructor of a subclass, but I'm not seeing it. The error I keep getting is that "Constructor Dog in class Dog cannot be applied to given types". I am really new to Java so any help you could give me would be great. Thank you in advance!

```
package dogtest;
public class DogTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Dog dog = new Dog("Spike");
    System.out.println(dog.getName() + " says " + dog.speak()); 

    Labrador boop = new Labrador(name, color);
    Yorkshire beep = new Yorkshire(name);
}}


package dogtest;
public class Dog {

protected String name;

public void Dog(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public String speak()
{
    return "Woof";
}}



package dogtest;
public class Labrador extends Dog{

private String color; 
private static int breedWeight = 75;

public Labrador(String name, String color)
{
    this.color = color;
}

public String speak()
{
    return "WOOF";
}

public static int avgBreedWeight()
{
    return breedWeight;
}}



package dogtest;
public class Yorkshire extends Dog {

public Yorkshire(String name)
{
    super(name);
}

public String speak()
{
    return "woof";
}}
```

Comment: You don't have a constructor receiving a string as argument, remove the `void` from `public void Dog(String name) { ... }`

Comment: every subclass of dog should call the super in the constructor.... just as info.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in comments, a constructor is similar to a method and it should have the same name as your class name `Dog` (you did this part right), but that they don't have a return type in their signature. So in order to have constructor with a `String` argument change the

```
public void Dog(String name) // this is only a method with the same name as the class
{
    this.name = name;
}
```

into

```
public Dog(String name) // this is a real constructor since doesn't have a return type
{
     this.name = name;
}
```

Before you change the above method into a constructor, the following error:

> "Constructor Dog in class Dog cannot be applied to given types"

is happening because when you don't specify a constructor explicitly, a default *no-arg* constructor would be added by the compiler. Then compiler gives you that error because it couldn't find a constructor with a `String` argument.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the compile errors of the code

- remove the void keyword of constrctor 'public void Dog(String name)'
- add super constructor call to the Labrador contractor 'super(name)'
- convert string to the name and color parameters in main method

  Labrador boop = new Labrador("name", "color");
    Yorkshire beep = new Yorkshire("name");

I did not add the packages and imports to the code

```
public class DogTest {


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dog dog = new Dog("Spike");
    System.out.println(dog.getName() + " says " + dog.speak());

    Labrador boop = new Labrador("name", "color");
    Yorkshire beep = new Yorkshire("name");
  }

}


class Dog {

  protected String name;

  public Dog(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public String speak() {
    return "Woof";
  }
}


class Labrador extends Dog {

  private String color;
  private static int breedWeight = 75;

  public Labrador(String name, String color) {
    super(name);
    this.color = color;
  }

  public String speak() {
    return "WOOF";
  }

  public static int avgBreedWeight() {
    return breedWeight;
  }
}

class Yorkshire extends Dog {

  public Yorkshire(String name) {
    super(name);
  }

  public String speak() {
    return "woof";
  }
}
```